# Debugger says currency is missing for product

Tags: debugging, facebook-opengraph, payment

The Facebook Object debugger [tells me](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://apps.facebook.com/cpuzzle_dev/opengraph/product/facebook.v16cashbundleXL.html):

> Object Missing a Required Value: Object at URL
>   'http://apps.facebook.com/cpuzzle_dev/opengraph/product/facebook.v16cashbundleXL.html'
>   of type 'product' is invalid because a required property
>   'product:price:currency' of type 'string' was not provided.

However, when I click on "[See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http://apps.facebook.com/cpuzzle_dev/opengraph/product/facebook.v16cashbundleXL.html)", I get:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta property="og:type" content="og:product">
<meta property="og:title" content="800 Puzzle Cash">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/assets/assets/platform/cash-stack-3.jpg">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://apps.facebook.com/cpuzzle_dev/opengraph/product/facebook.v16cashbundleS.html">
<meta property="og:description" content="A solid amount of Puzzle Cash">
<meta property="product:price:amount" content="3.80">
<meta property="product:price:currency" content="USD">
<meta property="product:price:amount" content="2.99">
<meta property="product:price:currency" content="EUR">
</head></html>
```

So what's the problem and how can I fix it?

Additional info: if I switch the order of the amount and currency elements, I get the same error, complaining about a missing "product:price:amount" property.

More additional info: I've change the product definition to match [that of Facebook's sample project](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https://www.friendsmash.com/opengraph/product_bomb.html) exactly (interestingly, the live sample project has the "product" namespace missing). For the sample project it works, for mine it doesn't...

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error, I finally found out how to get Facebook to accept the product definition.

The real problem doesn't seem to be with the structure or the currency property, but with the `og:url` property - apparently it must *not* be in the `apps.facebook.com` domain, but has to use your server domain. Once I changed that, the problem disappeared.